# XML Signed withSHA-256

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, ssl-certificate

i am trying to digitaliy sign XML File (SHA-256)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"F:\dev.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        string pfxpath = @"F:\dec.pfx";
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pfxpath), "Pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        signxml(doc, cert);
        File.WriteAllText(@"F:\a2.xml", doc.OuterXml);
    }
```

and this is my Function

```
public static void signxml(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {

        SignedXml signxm = new SignedXml(doc);
        signxm.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;
        signxm.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        Reference refrence = new Reference();
        refrence.Uri="";
        refrence.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        signxm.AddReference(refrence);
        KeyInfo key = new KeyInfo();
        key.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
        signxm.KeyInfo = key;
        signxm.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlsig = signxm.GetXml();
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlsig, true));
    }
```

there is an error 
in signxm.ComputeSignature();
and this is the description {"SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied."}
**So How To Solve it ??**

Comment: @softwariness Can help ??

Answer (score 0):

Standard .NET framework does not know how to translate `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256` to algorithm.

To solve this you need [Security.Cryptography.dll](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/). Follow [this guide](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription). You will have to

1. register the algorithm in .NET machine.config
2. add Security.Cryptography.dll to GAC (but it worked if I referenced it directly in my project too)